# How to mask out brush in After effects

Tags: after-effects

I've run into a little snag.
I can't seem to mask out some of the brush that I've used on a an empty layer.

I create the mask but it simply doesn't mask out anything, it does however mask out pixels when I did some experiments.

How can i get this done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a white solid, mask out what you want with that...then use it as an alpha matte to mask out what you do not want.

Comment: I imported my masks from Mocha AE, thus I got myself a vector mask and with that I would like to mask out some things including brush strokes. Any ideas on this one?

Comment: Yes just as I said above, apply that mask to a solid put it above the layer you want the mask applied to, then go to your layer select your track matte pull down (you may need to toggle to your trackmattes) and then select either alpha or alpha inverted